# Trying to understand how i can bind a WPF DP in a different class

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0, binding, bind

I am trying WPF to develop a tiny scoreboard.

In this project i have 3 XAML files.

ControlDisplay.xaml : Here is where i set the points for team 1 and team 2 in the scoreboard. Right now i only have 1 textbox for the scoreboard title.

Layout1.xaml : First layout, contains only a title for now.

Layout2.xaml : Second layout, same as above, only contains a title.

My idea is as following. I update one singleton class that has one property Title. Both Layout1 and Layout2's label for the title will bind to this singleton class property Title.

I created the basic structure for it.

ControlDisplay.xaml:

```
public partial class ControlDisplay : Window
{
    private IScoreboardData _scoreboardData;
    private Layout1 _layout1;
    private Layout2 _layout2;

    public ControlDisplay()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _scoreboardData = SimpleInjectorContainer.Container.GetInstance<IScoreboardData>();
    }

    private void ShowLayout1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _scoreboardData.Title = "Test";
        _layout1 = new Layout1();
        _layout1.Show();
    }

    private void ShowLayout2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _scoreboardData.Title = "Test";
        _layout2 = new Layout2();
        _layout2.Show();
    }
}
```

Layout1.xaml.cs (layout2 is a copy of layout1 codewise, just a different class name)

```
public partial class Layout1 : Window
{
    private IScoreboardData _scoreboardData;

    public Layout1()
    {
        _scoreboardData = SimpleInjectorContainer.Container.GetInstance<IScoreboardData>();
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Layout1.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="SmallScoreboard.Layout1" .... x:Name="LayoutOne">
    <StackPanel>
        <Label DataContext="{Binding ElementName=LayoutOne}" Content="{Binding _scoreboardData.Title}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

ScoreboardData.cs

```
public ScoreboardData : IScoreboardData
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

This obviously does not work since i don't register a dependency property anywhere? How can i register a dependency property inside the ScoreboardData class? or is there a better way to solve this?
I want to be able to add more layouts in the future and i hope that i don't have to add the base binding logic to each and everyone of those layout(x).xaml.cs files.

**Update**

This is my Layout1.xaml file right now:

```
<Window x:Class="Simple_Scoreboard.Layout1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Layout" Height="500" Width="800" 
        ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" 
        WindowStyle="None"
        AllowsTransparency="True"
        ResizeMode="CanResizeWithGrip"
        x:Name="LayoutOne" MouseLeftButtonDown="DWindow_MouseLeftButtonDown">
    <StackPanel>
        <Label Content="{Binding Path=Title, Mode=OneTime}" FontSize="30" HorizontalAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Margin="0,10,0,0" FontWeight="Bold"></Label>
    <Button Content="Button" Click="Button_Click_1"/>
    </StackPanel>
    </Window>
```

and the Layout1.xaml.cs

```
public partial class Layout1 : Window
    {
        public IScoreboardData _scoreboardData;

        public Layout1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _scoreboardData = ScoreboardContainer.Container.GetInstance<IScoreboardData>();
            DataContext = _scoreboardData;
        }

        private void DWindow_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            DragMove();
        }

        private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {                        
            _scoreboardData.Title = "Click change title";
        }
}
```

and finally the ScoreboardData class:

```
class ScoreboardData : IScoreboardData, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string _title;
        public string Title
        {
            get { return _title; }
            set
            {
                _title = value;
                if (PropertyChanged != null)
                    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Title"));
            }
        }  

        #region INotifyPropertyChanged

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        #endregion
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is in binding to a private field _scoreboardData;
you should make it a public property. But much better solution would be to bind to a window DataContext.

in the window constructor

```
public Layout1()
{
    _scoreboardData = SimpleInjectorContainer.Container.GetInstance<IScoreboardData>();
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = _scoreboardData;
}
```

In the XAML

```
<Window x:Class="SmallScoreboard.Layout1" .... x:Name="LayoutOne">
   <StackPanel>
      <Label Text="{Binding Title}" />
   </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

This way you have your scoreBoardData as Window DataContext and all bindings without explicitly specified source will bind to that object.

UPDATE:
ScoreboardData should implement INotifyPropertyChanged..

```
 public class ScoreboardData :IScoreboardData, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged
 {
     public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
     private string _title;
     public string Title
      {
          get { return _title; }
          set 
          {
              _title = value; 
               if(PropertyChanged!=null)
                  PropertyChanged(this,new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Title"));
          }
       }                
  }
```

Comment: Isn't a dependency property needed?

Comment: No, you don't need dependency property for this. What you should do is implement INotifyPropertyChange in ScoreboardData and raise PropertyChanged event in the Title property setter. That is  required for binding to be notified when the Title value changes.

Comment: I get it to show, but i can not get it to update the value if i try to set a new value. What do i do with the event property changed? I need to subscribe to that somehow and get the label to understand it.

Comment: No need to subscribe, Binding will do that if the source object implements INotifyPropertyChanged. I updated the answer with expample.

Comment: I made an update above to exactly what it looks like right now. When i debug then i can see that PropertyChanged is null thus never invoked.

Comment: Saw the problem. Solved. Should not be OneTime above, but OneWay.